# Помогите нарисовать поле для пинпонга в консоли, на си

Tags: c, консоль, рисование

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x = 80;
    int y = 0;

while (y != 26 ) { 
    y = y + 1;
    for(int i = 0; x >= i; i++) {
        if((y == 1) || (y == 26)) {
            printf("-");
        } else {
            if(((i == 0) || (i == 70)) && ((y != 1) || (y != 26))) {
                printf("|");
            } else { 
                if ((y == 2) && (i == 40)) {
                    printf("%d||%d", 0, 0);
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { 
                if((i == 2) && (y == 12+j)) { 
                    printf("]");
                    }
                }
                for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++) { 
                if((i == 75) && (y == 12+b)) { 
                    printf("[");
                    }
                }
                if((i == 4) && (y == 12)) { 
                    printf("*");
                }
                
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Съезжает правый край, как выровнять?

Answer (score 1):

> как выровнять?

Но у Вас строки **действительно** разной длины.

Происходит это вот почему:

1. Вы организуете цикл печати по строке с помощью переменной *i*
2. В заголовке цикла проверяется, что цикл выполняется 80 раз - в соответствии с шириной строки.
3. Однако, внутри цикла есть операторы печати, вроде *printf("%d||%d", 0, 0);* которые печатаю не один символ, а несколько. В данном случае - 4 символа.
4. Соответственно, строка получается длиннее 80 символов.

Что бы исправить ситуацию, достаточно после этого оператора печати вставить

```
i+=4;
```

И аналогично поступить для остальных операторов печати внутри цикла.